# ObjectId of MongoDB in ecommerce web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, database-design, database-schema, mongomapper

I want to create a database for ecommerce web application using mongoDB[image: almost similar to it]

I am not able to get the idea how to set primary key for it as for every entry it automatically create id which is unique so I can use it as primary key
In mongoDB terminal

> db.department.findOne({dep_name :"clothing"})
>       { "_id" : ObjectId("5277d82f658d9f107b7ae64e"), "dep_name" : "clothing" }

For the department clothing the dep_id is ObjectId("5277d82f658d9f107b7ae64e")
and while creating category of men,women,kids the dep_id will remain same and at the same time other object id will get created which act as cat_id(unique for men,women,kids).
I am not getting idea how to get dep_id where dep_name is clothing and insert the dep_id for the new collection which will have fields ObjectId(automatically created),dep_id,cat_name.

Apart from it if this seems not to be good idea for creating database for ecommerce web application then suggest what will be the best

Comment: I'm not following your question. Is there anything else you could add to make it more clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @WirePrairie ---Bruce answers the question but I want to confirm is it the correct way for the allocation of primary key for ecommerce web application or if there is any other method which is better then i will opt it in devlopement.

Comment: Without Joins, you're going to need to specially handle building the relationships you want efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are asking how, for
example, to insert a document in a "category" collection that contains
a "dep_id" field containing the _id of a department such as
"clothing"?

Here is an example of how you would do that using the mongo shell:

```
clothing = db.department.findOne({dep_name: "clothing"})
db.category.insert({dep_id: clothing._id, cat_name: "women"})
```

Does this answer your question?

Bruce

Comment: Thanks for the reply.It answers the question but I want to confirm that is it the correct method of allocating primary key for ecommerce web app ,or if you any suggestion then please share.I really appreciate that.